# How to refresh content View on Body after add or crud data in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm the newbie Flutter Developer. I got any problem when I tap the custom drawer,  body content viewed the widget after that I tap add button with api and success created new data. but when back to drawer can't reload automatically. below are some of my codecs.

I user drawerbehavior version 0.0.8

**MyCustomDrawer code**

```
DrawerScaffold(
  percentage: 1,
  cornerRadius: 0,
  appBar: AppBarProps(
      title: Text(
        "ToDO",
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Acme'),
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
      actions: [
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () => tambahAgenda(context, '4', true))
      ]),
  menuView: new MenuView(
    menu: menu,
    headerView: headerView(context),
    footerView: footerView(context),
    animation: false,
    textStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Acme', color: Colors.white),
    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    selectedItemId: selectedMenuItemId,
    onMenuItemSelected: (String itemId) {
      selectedMenuItemId = itemId;
      if (itemId == 'beranda') {
        setState(() => _widget = IsiBerandaUI());
      } else if (itemId == 'agenda') {
        setState(() => _widget = Container());
      } else if (itemId == 'kalenderagenda') {
        setState(() => _widget = AgendaCalendarUI());
      }
    },
  ),
  contentView: Screen(
    contentBuilder: (context) => Center(child: _widget),
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
);
 _navigateAndDisplaySelection(
  BuildContext context, String idKategori, bool statusLogin) async {
final result = await Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TambahAgendaUI()),
);

if (result != null) {
  // bloc.fetchAllAgendaTGL(idKategori, statusLogin);
  setState(() {
    selectedMenuItemId = 'kalenderagenda';
    _widget = AgendaCalendarUI();
  });
   Navigator.pushReplacement(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (BuildContext context) => Beranda(
                 selectedMenuItemId: 'kalenderagenda',
               )));
   Scaffold.of(context)
     ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
     ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
         content: Text(
       "$result",
       style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'googleSans'),
     )));
}
```

}

and myadd data navigator like this

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => Beranda(
            selectedMenuItemId: 'kalenderagenda',
        )
    )
);
```

But When I pushReplacement widget get any error.
any conclusion ???